# Timeline CSS Card Sequence

Tags: css

I am not able to get the timeline sequence in the correct order. I am able to do so far get in this order but is wrong:

1

```
   2
```

3

4

What I wanted in this order is:

1

```
   2
```

3

```
   4
```

Here are the CSS and the HTML code that I used

```
.demo-card:nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.demo-card:nth-child(2) {
  order: 4;
}

.demo-card:nth-child(3) {
  order: 2;
}

.demo-card:nth-child(4) {
  order: 3;
}


#timeline .demo-card--step1 {
  background-color: #46b8e9;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step1 .head::after {
  border-color: #46b8e9;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step2 {
  background-color: #3ee9d1;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step2 .head::after {
  border-color: #3ee9d1;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step3 {
  background-color: #ce43eb;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step3 .head::after {
  border-color: #ce43eb;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step4 {
  background-color: #4d92eb;
}
#timeline .demo-card--step4 .head::after {
  border-color: #4d92eb;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="demo-card demo-card--step1">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="number-box">
      <span>01</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="demo-card demo-card--step2">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="number-box">
      <span>02</span>
    </div>                          
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>

<div class="demo-card demo-card--step3">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="number-box">
      <span>03</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>

<div class="demo-card demo-card--step4">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="number-box">
      <span>04</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

The Flexbox Timeline is based on this https://codepen.io/paulhbarker/pen/apvGdv/

Thanks and I greatly appreciated the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a simple sample that will allow you to add as many timeline items as u need with the use of `nth-child(even/odd)`

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* debug */
  border: 1px dashed tomato;
}

.timeline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.timeline-item {
  width: 100px;  
  height: 100px;  
}

.timeline-item:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translateX(-60%);
  background-color: green;
}

.timeline-item:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateX(60%);
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='timeline'>
  <div class='timeline-item'></div>
  <div class='timeline-item'></div>
  <div class='timeline-item'></div>
  <div class='timeline-item'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what if I want different colors for each timeline? Thanks again

Comment: Are you using plain css or a preprocessor ?

Comment: I am using this code here https://codepen.io/paulhbarker/pen/apvGdv/ but I just need 4 items. Thanks